# Query Performance effects

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I just want to ask if with this kind of database design below and query below will this have a big effect on the query performance or should I break down the query instead of multiple subqueries. Though this subquery works for me I just want to make sure that someday it will not affect the performance. My goal in mind with this query is that I want to generate a dynamic queries for all those table. Example query for this is to view list of participants attended in a specific commodity and start date between 2 given date.Thank you in advance.

[image]

Below is my sample code that will view participants in between 1 and 3 years old.

```
    SELECT TT.title, TTP.*, TS.*, TP.lastname, TP.firstname, (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(TP.birthday, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(TP.birthday, '00-%m-%d')) )AS age, TP.birthday
FROM tbl_trainingparticipant AS TTP 
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT t1.* 
    FROM tbl_schedules t1
    WHERE t1.sched_id = (
        SELECT t2.sched_id 
        FROM tbl_schedules t2 
        WHERE t2.training_id = t1.training_id 
        ORDER BY t2.sched_id DESC LIMIT 1 
    ) 
)AS TS ON TTP.training_id = TS.training_id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_participants AS TP 
ON TTP.participant_id = TP.participant_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_trainings AS TT
ON TT.training_id = TS.training_id
HAVING age BETWEEN 1 AND 3
```

Comment: This probably belongs on code review.

Comment: Only you know what performance impact it will have with your data set, and what performance you consider acceptable. Implement, test, measure, analyze, optimize.

Comment: Two tables with over 10 columns each with a "relationship" table joining them together. Pretty standard. You certainly wouldn't want to combine them into 1 table. The sub-query for schedules is a little messy, but I guess if you need to choose only the most recent schedule for each training session that ought to do it.  If `tbl_schedules` <-> `tbl_trainings` should always be 1-1, then make `training_id` unique in `tbl_schedules`.

Answer (score 0):

> SQL has an ability to nest queries within one another. A subquery is a
>   SELECT statement that is nested within another SELECT statement and
>   which return intermediate results. SQL executes innermost subquery
>   first, then next level.

So if you use a nested select you assigned task to mysql to execute two queries which are sent to it together. Usually it's going to be faster to do one trip than several.

Comment: My experience with mysql queries is performance is unpredictable and finicky.  Many times I've modified a query by simply moving logic into a sub-query and found several-fold performance increase.  Some in-memory row operations may be slower than key look-ups, but reducing the overall row-count as quickly as possible and keeping it down is the only semi-sure way to reduce query times.  `EXPLAIN` will even try to count the rows for you.

Comment: @ebyrob Yes, sure I believe you, but any rule can have some exceptions. What I said is a rule and experiencing will give the most accurate answer.

Comment: You seem to be making up a rule about multiple execution units being slower than a single larger execution unit?  I was just pointing out this runs counter to all my experience and to what little theory I know on the matter.  (for one thing problem solving itself is breaking problems down into smaller pieces)  Keep in mind MySQL isn't sending pieces of the query across the network, it's all already on a single instance.

Comment: @ebyrob It's not your problem. It's a query from a DBMS. Let the programmers on oracle to break out and solve it. No nead to send pieses of the problem along a network. They execute queries from the inner one to outter. But about your experience; which one is faster 1000 of selections with limit 1 or 1 query with limit 1000?

Comment: @ebyrob The connection to the database server should be closed as fast as possible.